# How to keep the value of textinput when going from screen B to screen A in React-Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have 2 screens A and B, in screen A I have a TextInput, it's value is taken from another screen to this screen, its code looks like this

```
const ScreenA = (props) => {
    const { position, suffix } = props;

    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState(props.name || '');

    const navigationScreen = () => {
        navigation.navigate('screenB');
    };

    return (
        <>
            <View>
                <View>
                    <TextInput
                        value={textValue}
                        onChangeText={(text) => {
                            setTextValue(text);
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigationScreen}>
                    <View>
                        <View style={styles.rectangle} />
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </>
    );
};

export default ScreenA;
```

And after I press the button in screen A it moves to screen B, but after I go back from screen B to screen A, how can I keep my changed value at screen A,

The example is as follows: initially I go to screen A, the value of textValue will be "Abcd", then I edit the value of TextInput to be "A913" then I press submit button, and when in screen B rotates about screen A, i want the value of TextInput to be "A913" not "Abcd"

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Tried storing the textInput value to global state and change the global state onChangeText, so that when you come again it will fetch the global state

Answer (score 0):

You should store your textinput value in Global state. and you can do so by using [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org)